# Haskell Monads and the liftIO I don't get it

Tags: haskell, monads, io-monad, scotty, lifting

Hello community thank you for your time.

I have an error and I am not sure what the error is, but what I think the problem is:
There is no IO transformer from `ext-1.2.4.1:Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text IO)` to `Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ScottyT`.

But I wondering why the compiler works with `ext-1.2.4.1:Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text IO)`. That's why I am working just with String and I removed all occurrences of `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` but still get the error. On the other hand, this should be `IO [String]`, shouldn't it?
And as you can mention I don't really know what `ext-1.2.4.1:Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text IO)` is.

At another place, I already use `liftIO` successfully for an `a -> IO String` function. And I think I use them the same way.

I think I get slowly a feeling for what a monad is, but not quite sure. *I don't really know why I have to use a `lift` function at all.*

Error message:

```
    • No instance for (MonadIO
                         (Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ScottyT
                            text-1.2.4.1:Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text IO))
        arising from a use of ‘liftIO’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        paths <- liftIO $ getAllFilePaths2 path
      In the expression:
        do paths <- liftIO $ getAllFilePaths2 path
           pathsToScotty paths
      In an equation for ‘pathsToScotty2’:
          pathsToScotty2 path
            = do paths <- liftIO $ getAllFilePaths2 path
                 pathsToScotty paths
   |        
49 |    paths <- liftIO $ getAllFilePaths2  path
```

Where the error occurred:

```hs
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
...
pathsToScotty2 :: String -> ScottyM ()
pathsToScotty2 path = do
   paths <- liftIO $ getAllFilePaths2  path
   pathsToScotty paths
```

```hs
getAllFilePaths2 :: String -> IO [String]
getAllFilePaths2 dir = do
    putStrLn dir
    isFile <- doesFileExist dir 
    if isFile 
        then return [dir] 
        else do
          dirs <- listDirectory dir
          foldl foldHelper2 (return []) $ map (\d -> show $ mconcat [dir, "/",d ]) dirs


foldHelper2 :: IO [String] -> String  -> IO [String]
foldHelper2 ps path = do 
    paths <- ps
    newPaths <- getAllFilePaths2 path
    return (paths ++ newPaths)
```

Comment: Minor point: you are misreading the error message. That has the form `No instance for (MonadIO (X Y Z))` where `X=Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ScottyT`, `Y=text-1.2.4.1:Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text` and `Z=IO`. In your question you mention `Y Z` as if that was a type, but it is not. `Z` is the second argument of `X`, not the first one of `Y` (which does not take arguments).

Comment: ScottyM has to be an instance of MonadIO. which if it is a monad transformer over IO, you should be able to derive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Truly understanding monads takes time, practice, and patience, but it shouldn't be too hard to understand the need for `liftIO` by examining your types.

First off, the type of `liftIO` is `MonadIO m => IO a -> m a`.  This means that the function can convert any IO action into an action in the monad `m` so long as `m` has an instance of `MonadIO`.  In theory, this can only be implemented if `m` has some way of processing `IO` actions, so this function is embedding the given action into the `m` monad.

You're definitely in the right sort of place to use `liftIO`, so why isn't it working?  That is, you have a value `getAllFilePaths2 path` of type `IO [String]`, and you'd like it to be a value of type `ScottyM [String]` — this indeed seems like a good place to use `liftIO`.  However, `ScottyM` is *not* an instance of `MonadIO`, as that error message you saw is trying to tell you, so you can't use `liftIO`.

This may seem crazy—can you really not embed IO actions into `ScottyM`?—but there's actually a good reason for this.  What happens if the `IO` action throws an error?  Does your whole web app crash?  It would if you naively used `liftIO`.  Instead, scotty provides the function [`liftAndCatchIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.12/docs/Web-Scotty.html#v:liftAndCatchIO), which, as the docs describe, is "Like `liftIO`, but catch any IO exceptions and turn them into Scotty exceptions."  This is the preferred way to embed `IO` actions into Scotty.

And here comes the final gotcha: Note that `liftAndCatchIO` actually produces values of type `ActionM a`, not `ScottyM a`.  Additionally, there's no way to take a value in the `ActionM` monad and get it into the `ScottyM` monad.  Instead, you need to use that value as an action.  So, I'm not sure what `pathsToScotty` does, but it's very likely that you'll need to rewrite it.